# PostgreSQL Function or Python Script to export table data to csv after every hour

Tags: python, postgresql, function, shell, export

I want to export my postgreSQL table data to csv file. The problem is that, this table is updated after every minute and I want to create that csv file with date on it's name and it will contain the data of the previous hour.

For example: The table name is ***rectifier*** and it's csv files will be **15:00-15:59-01-04-2019-rectifier.csv** and **16:00-16:59-01-04-2019-rectifier.csv** these files will contain the data of the mentioned hour. This script of function will run after every hour and create the files with the time and date details on them.

I've gone through different tutorials but they only show how to copy the data once.

How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different tasks:

1. Export data to file
2. Run export by the schedule

If you know how to implement the 1st task, then the problem is only in the 2nd one - run it periodically.

You need a scheduler:
1. in python it can be implemented using Celery
2. or, simply, using os-level cron (for *nix) or windows scheduler